# Call GitLab API without personal "Private Token"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Is there a way to call GitLab API apart from using personal "PRIVATE TOKEN"?

Problem with PRIVATE TOKEN is , it need to be updated in settings -> CI/CD -> Environment Variables which is accessible to anyone with maintainer privilege.

And its need to be updated, if the developer moves out of the project .

I found out there is no other way to do it and alternate implementation still in GitLab's backlog.

But just to ensure & looking for if there is any other work around exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Gitlab 13.9, there's no way to use the API without someone's access token, but you could create a "dummy" Gitlab user and use an access token of theirs if you didn't want to use one belonging to a person.